# Is it an anti-pattern to extract specific children to control where they are rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating a reusable `ContentHeading` control that takes in an optional menu and submenu. Both the menu and submenu have very specific places I want them to render. The thing is, I need to give consumers of this component plenty of control over either menu to tailor it to the needs of their view.

Usually, I would just create two optional props for the component that can take in a `Menu`, and optionally render them where I need them if they are present. This works, but it looks a little messy declaratively, to me at least.

So I thought another possibility is to let them place the menus they want in their headers and assign them a specific key, and have `render` remove those from children and render them where I want, and all other children can be rendered as the heading.

Here's the code in question:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { Grid, Menu, Header } from '../';

export interface ContentHeaderProps {
  heading?: string | React.ReactNode;
}

export class ContentHeader extends React.Component<ContentHeaderProps> {
  getComponent(children: React.ReactChild[], key: string) {
    return children.find((child: any) => {
      return (child.key && child.key === key);
    });
  }
  getHeadingComponents(children: React.ReactChild[]) {
    return children.filter((child: any) => {
      return !child.key || (child.key !== '.$menu' && child.key !== '.$submenu');
    });
  }
  render() {   
    const children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);

    let heading;

    if (this.props.heading) {
      heading = this.props.heading;
    } else {
      heading = this.getHeadingComponents(children);
    }

    const menu = this.getComponent(children, '.$menu');
    const submenu = this.getComponent(children, '.$submenu');

    return (
      <div className="menu content">
        <Grid container padded="vertically">
          <Grid.Row>
            <Header
              floated="left"
            >
              {heading}
            </Header>
            {menu}
          </Grid.Row>
        </Grid>
        {submenu}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here it is in use:

```
<ContentHeader>
  <Menu key="menu">
    <Menu.Item>Test Menu</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
  <Menu key="submenu">
    <Menu.Item>Test Submenu</Menu.Item>
  </Menu>
  Welcome!
</ContentHeader>
```

It works, but I'm not sure if this is an antipattern. I suppose the problem is that it's opaque what the capabilities of the component are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not bad, in the end it's going to be all a matter of opinion and choice. If it works for you and you feel that it's maintainable, then that's fine.

However if I was to offer some guidance, what I would do is make those both be properties and where you then use the ContentHeader component, i'd create functions to return the items or store them in variables prior to there use and reference the variables.

```
<ContentHeader menu={this.createMenu()} subMenu={this.createSubMenu()}>
</ContentHeader>
```

The other option is that you could create the sub items as there own react components and pass in the component type as the value to the property and then use that component type, along with a list of items, to create the internal components by mapping over the list and creating the component.

The main value to all these is to increase test ability and reduce maintenance overhead.